# ReactJs - Call function after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components; Parent, ChildA, Child B. The parent is defined like this:

```
class Parents extends Component {
   getPersons = () => {
       fetch('/Persons')
        .then(persons => this.setState({ persons:persons })
     }

   updateTable = () => 
       this.setState({ update: true })
 }
```

Now, ChildA is a form where I can create new *persons*. ChildB is a table showing all the persons. I would like ChildB to re render when I have created a new person.

I tried to call an updateTable() function on childA immediately after getPerons(), like this:

```
class ChildA extends Component {
   onSubmit() {
    this.getPersons();
    this.updateTable();
   }
 }
```

The issue is that the table is updated before persons are fetched.
What is the correct way to handle this?

I guess could define the getPersons() in childA and then add ".then(this.updateTable())" but I am using the getPersons in initial rendering as well, so I don't want to move it away from Parent

Comment: What is `this.getTeachers();`?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - Sorry, edited now to this.getPersons(); - My mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to continue the promise chain all in the same place. The first function can return the promise and you can continue the chain wherever you want.

```
class Parents extends Component {
   // remove the brackets to return the promise
   getPersons = () => fetch('/Persons')
        .then(persons => this.setState({ persons:persons })

   updateTable = () => 
       this.setState({ update: true })
 }

class ChildA extends Component {
  onSubmit() {
    this.getPersons().then( this.updateTable );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did what you propsed in ChildA and getting a "Cannot read property then of undefined" error? Not quite sure why - Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex5207 You need to also change the `getPersons` function to return `fetch`.

Comment: @Baruch - Yeah that seems to what I am doing wrong. Not quite sure how to do it, though. How can I return the fetch and still set state in the function?

Comment: @Alex5207 Please, re-read JJJ's answer carefully. The answer is literally in the second line of the example code.

Comment: I see - Wasn't aware that you could omit the return statement. It works now, amazing - Thank you both